# Construction of ColorConvertedBitmap fails when there are 500 live instances

Tags: c#, .net

I work on a big application that processes photos. There are some circumstances when the application can create more than 500 instances of the ColorConvertedBitmap class. Unfortunately it always fails when trying to create 501, 502, ... instances. I get FileFormatException with the message "Bitmap color context is not valid." However I use the same source and destination color contexts for all instances and the first 500 instances don't fail. Is it a bug or there are some resource limitations with the color management subsystem of .NET Framework\OS?

[EDIT]
The following fragment of code reproduces the problem on my computer:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
ColorContext sourceColorContext = new ColorContext(new Uri(@"d:\!work\ICC\AdobeRGB1998.icc"));
ColorContext destinationColorContext = new ColorContext(new Uri(@"d:\!work\ICC\sRGB Color Space Profile.icm"));
foreach (var file in files)
{
  BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(file));
  ColorConvertedBitmap coloredBitmap = new ColorConvertedBitmap(image, sourceColorContext,  destinationColorContext, image.Format);
  this.bitmaps.Add(coloredBitmap);
}
```

P.S. I use Windows 8.

Comment: Even after trying Google Glasses I am not able to see your code, can you put your code here?

Comment: It seems Google Glasses ignores all the content that touches Microsoft technologies. Try now without them ;)

Comment: Change the Platform target setting on your EXE project to AnyCPU, turn off "Prefer 32-bit" on VS2012+, and try again.

Comment: Hans, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, it didn't help. The problem is still reproduced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft has answered the question:

"This seems to be a resource limitation of the Windows Imaging Component - WIC. WPF is merely forwarding an error code returned by IWICColorTransform_Initialize_Proxy (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg430025(v=VS.85).aspx)."

[The issue is on Microsoft Connect.](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/798140/construction-of-colorconvertedbitmap-fails-when-there-are-500-live-instances)